# Is there a cost difference if I want to access AWS resources from a geographically nearer location to the end user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-iot

Is there any cost difference or any other type of difference(latency, performance, data corruption etc.) for regions?? I am making primarily a IoT service stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each region has its own prices for services, this will generally vary marginally with some regions (such as `us-east-1`, `eu-west-1`) generally costing less overall.

Generally data transfer itself is the same from the source to destination (defined at the region level), however [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/) does charge depending on the nearest edge location to the user.

Latency will definitely impact your end users so it is worth investing in a region closer to them so that this can be minimised. You can get a rough guideline from [CloudPing](https://www.cloudping.co/grid).

You should check each services pricing page to get more of a breakdown of the overall costs you'd pay in a region. However, generally you need to decide between performance and cost so you should evaluate between the both of these.

Also bare in mind that new service releases and features are rolled out to specific regions at a time, if you want to use the latest features you may want to decide on a region that is known to get them earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In Short Yes.. Each region in AWS has different costs associated with same services. There are some exceptions as well but generally it s the case. e.g. IOT Core service prices in US East region is $0.08 (per million minutes of connection) vs $0.092 (per million minutes of connection) in ASIA Pacific region. This is 15% increase but if you are going to use let's say 100 million minutes of connections then the difference is just around a Dollar!!!

However if any of your device in Asia region wants to send some data to US Region then there will definitely be latency & performance issues. So it is always better to use nearby region. You can always go to the pricing page of AWS Service you are going to use and check Costs.